# ELF tool to dump function addresses alongside their symbols

Tags: linux, elf, objdump

I've recently come across an issue with objdump where instead of printing the function's symbol as a label, it repeats the first instruction over and over a few times.

```
ca719c: 009501b4            ; <UNDEFINED> instruction: 0x009501b4

ca71a0: 00082574    andeq   r2, r8, r4, ror r5

ca71a4: 00950198    umullseq    r0, r5, r8, r1

ca71a8: 0002e468    andeq   lr, r2, r8, ror #8

ca71ac: 00950164    addseq  r0, r5, r4, ror #2

ca71b0: 0000b124    andeq   fp, r0, r4, lsr #2

ca71b4: e12fff1e    bx  lr

ca71b8: e12fff1e    bx  lr

ca71bc: e12fff1e    bx  lr

ca71c0: e12fff1e    bx  lr

ca71c4: e12fff1e    bx  lr
...`
```

To address and get around this, i was wondering if there is a tool for linux that can dump all the function addresses and print their corresponding symbols alongside them, so i know what to look for and where to start/stop.

Thanks.

Comment: readelf -s in Ubuntu?

Comment: Did you specify the wrong subtarget for the disassembly?